# Can Not Get file EJS Under Views Directory

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs

In this problem, I tried to render ejs after update the data from UI. Here is my code,

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParse = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({ extends: true }));
var path = require('path');

let items = ["Buy Food", "Cook Food", "Eat Food"];
let itemWorks = [];

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let day = date.getDay();

  res.render(path.join(__dirname + "/views/list.ejs"), { listTitle: day, listItem: items });
  items.pop;

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

  let item = req.body.foodservice;
  if(res.body.list === "work"){
    itemWorks.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");    
  }else{
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }

  items.push(item);
  res.redirect("/");
});
});
```

Here is my list.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%=listTitle%></h1>
    <ul>
      <% for(var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++){ %>
      <li><%=listItem[i]%></li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="foodservice" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off"/><br /><br />
      <button type="submit" name="button" value=<%=listTitle%>>+</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my project's structure:
`BRANDNEW_PROJECT views /list.ejs app.js data.js`

However, when I have executed it=> errors have been displayed as bellow

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')
    at E:\WEB DEVELOPMENT\NodeJS\BrandNew_Project\app.js:25:15
```

I have tried to debug by putting log to check whether it already points to file that I want or not and the path is correct and also to tried set up file path like this:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

However, the issues have not been resolved.

What can be the reason here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Live working URL** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dmtquz?file=index.js

**Views folder is default in EJS.**

**Concept:**
when render html pages you must take care path will start for other inside views as root

1. when render html pages you must take care path will start for other inside views as root.
2. Not render **views/layouts/index** use **layout/index** because,**EJS** make views (or your directory) as active directory for it.
3. if you want to change the directory use **app.set("views", path.join(path.resolve(), < dir name >)).**

Structure:

- views 
  -------- layouts 
  ---------------- index.ejs (this file i rendered as root) 
  -------- partials 
  -----------------footer.ejs, header.ejs etc

Hope this will clear up your problem

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
// app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("layouts/index" , {
    displayTitle: "items viewer",
    item: ["item1", "item2"]
  });
});

// about page
app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("layouts/about");
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is listening on port 8080");
```

```html
<!-- root dir, views/layout/list.ejs  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <%= displayTitle%>
    <hr />
    <% for (let i of items) { %>
    <br />
    <%= i %> <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Jerry, the index.html file that I do not want to render it, it just the template that I use it later. I just want to render the data to EJS that has logic to loading my data. I tried at the first time to use app.set("view engine", "ejs"). However, the issue has not been resolved yet.

Comment: Hi @tonydn, there is not index.html file it is index.ejs is there and in ejs a main root file is required to render its child component in it. from this solution now you can pass data  what you want.

please Check my updated Solution and see structure of folder and files.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, updated code again:

res.render("list.ejs", { listTitle: day, listItem: items });

However. the error has the same before: 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')

Comment: Can you explain/mention me the path of list.ejs From your project root dir

Comment: The structure of my project as below:
BRANDNEW_PROJECT
/node_modules
/views
    /list.ejs
app.js
date.js
index.html
package.json
package-lock.json

It means that the views folder is the same hierarchy with node_modules and the rest of file

Comment: Hey @tonydn, please visit this link 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dmtquz?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `path.resolve` instead of `path.join` like this:

```
res.render(path.resolve(__dirname + "/views/list.ejs"), { listTitle: day, listItem: items });
```

You might also need to update your import of the date object at the top to use `path.resolve` like this:

```
const date = require(path.resolve(__dirname + "/date.js"));
```

In my code I use `path.resolve` anytime I use `__dirname`

Comment: Hi @Dustin Spengler, First of all, thank for providing to me the way to solve it. However, when I tried to use method resolve to point to list.ejs. The issue has not been resolved yet.